# Программное создание базы данных на C#

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

Как программно создать базу данных на языке *C#* (использую *IDE Visual Studio*) при нажатии, например, на кнопку (*Button*)?

Необходимо реализовать возможность именно программного создания базы данных, подключиться к ней, дабы впоследующем создать в ней две таблицы, и редактировать их путем стандартных запросов - `insert`, `delete`, `update`, `select`.

Иными словами, необходимо создать в текущем каталоге где расположен сам `*.exe`, хранилище информации в виде базы данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Ваших целей можно использовать [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/)

Для этого Вам нужно:

1. Добавить ссылку на библиотеку SQLite через NuGet, или любым другим способом.
2. Создать файл базы данных:

   ```
   if (!File.Exists("test.db"))
       SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("test.db");
   ```
3. Использовать созданную БД:

   ```
   using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db"))
   {
       connection.Open();
       using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
       {
           cmd.CommandText = @"create table if not exists [TestTable](
                                   [id] integer not null primary key autoincrement,
                                   [value] nvarchar(2048) null
                               );";
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           cmd.CommandText = "insert into TestTable (value) values(:value)";
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("value", "abc");
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           cmd.CommandText = "select * from TestTable";
           using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
               while (reader.Read())
                   Console.WriteLine("Id={0}, Value={1}", reader["id"], reader["value"]);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

База данных создаётся с помощью инструкции `CREATE DATABASE` или `CREATE SCHEMA` (подробнее [здесь](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)), а таблицы с помощью инструкции `CREATE TABLE` (подробнее [здесь](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)).

Что касается создания БД в папке программы. Всё зависит от того, с какой версией MySQL требуется работать. "Обычной" или [встраиваемой](http://www.mysql.com/oem/), .

Так как MySQL - клиент-серверная СУБД, нет смысла помещать файлы БД в папку с программой. Программа всё равно будет обращаться к серверу. Да, это и не получится (если не ошибаюсь, MySQL не позволяет задавать для БД отдельную папку). Правда всё это относится "обычной" версии.